# NUnit Throwing InvalidOperationException: Service Manager failed to initialize RecentFilesService

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit, resharper

My laptop did a bluescreen when I was running some unit tests, and now nothing I can do will make it able to run tests again.

I am attempting to run tests that are programmed against NUnit 3.2 using Resharper, although Resharper reports that the problem is in NUnit.  I pulled the NUnit code down from GitHub and it looks like the error is thrown if the RecentFilesService is unable to find a particular setting from the settings file.  I have searched my computer for this file and cannot find it.  I have reinstalled all of the NUnit packages in my project as well as reinstalled Resharper.

At this point, I am pretty much DOA.  I need to figure out how to reset this file to its correct state, or else simply bypass this error.

[image]

Comment: The error is thrown if *any* required service fails to initialize. Check what version of the NUnit engine is being used by resharper and what version is being installed by your project. It's the engine that matters here, not the framework. I can probably give an answer if you post that information.

Comment: Resharper says it is using the version 3.3.0.12 runner.

Comment: I was able to track down the problem to the file Nunit30Settings.xml, which had become corrupted and was full of null characters.  I deleted the file and everything ran fine and the file was regenerated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution yet?

Comment: Yes, if you read my comment above, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to track down the problem to the file Nunit30Settings.xml, which had become corrupted and was full of null characters. I deleted the file and everything ran fine and the file was regenerated. This file is in your [User]\AppData\Local\NUnit folder.

Comment: Thanks! This saved me hours!

Comment: Best solution ever!

Answer (score 2):

@drz, thank you for above information. It was very helpful. I can not comment or vote so adding your answer here

> "Nunit30Settings.xml, becomes corrupted so delete the file at 
>   [User]\AppData\Local\NUnit folder. File will be generated again."

Comment: better than the answer in the comments above, gives path to file and makes solution clear +1.